# Using Matlab's intlinprog (mixed-integer linear programming) for multi-objective optimization?

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I have previously used MATLAB'S intlinprog solver to minimize one variable, x. Is there a way to use the same solver to minimize two variables at once (aka, both x AND y simultaneously)?

[Quick description of intlinprog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxRb6.png)

Comment: Well. If you got a model of your type of multi-objective, you could try to formulate the intlinprog-objective as some specific function on these variables (needs to be linear or convex; depending on your solver). But without a model, no one can help. Maybe you want to minimize ```x+y```, but maybe you want to minimize ```bigM * x + y``` or some more complex objective like absolute orders...

Comment: There are many multi-objective methods that use a standard LP/MIP solver. Weighted sum or some other scalarization method or the lexicographic method comes to mind. You may want to do some reading on multi-objective optimization (aka multi-criteria optimization).